# Changing the font color of the sticky menu when scrolling nav bar?

Tags: html, css

My code here:

```
  //02. sticky menu
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll < 5) {
            $("#header-sticky").removeClass("sticky-menu");
        } else {
            $("#header-sticky").addClass("sticky-menu");
        }
    });
```

When scroll navbar adding sticky-menu. navbar font color default #000. When scrolling navbar, how to use my navbar font color #fff?

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS please?

Comment: its work,thank you
.sticky-menu .main-menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your css

```
.sticky-menu{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: its work,thank brother

 .sticky-menu .main-menu ul li a { color: #fff; }

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!  You find the **sticky-menu** Css class and Add following the code.

```
color: #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--header start-->
    <header id="header-sticky" class="align-items-center d-flex">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row rowss">
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                    <!--logo start-->
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo-01.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <!--logo end-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9">
                    <!--menu start-->
                    <div class="main-menu f-right">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="menu_link">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about" class="menu_link">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service" class="menu_link">Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown_toggler">Pages<i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="index-02.html">Home page 02</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="about.html">About Page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="service.html">Service Page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="team.html">Team Page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing Page</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog Grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="blog-details.html">Blog Left</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="menu_link">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="menu_link">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact" class="menu_link">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <!--menu end-->
                </div>

                <!-- navbar toggler btn -->
                <div class="nav-toggler d-md-block d-lg-none">
                    <i class="ti-menu-alt"></i>
                    <i class="ti-close"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--header end-->
```

Comment: I believe my answer solves your problem. as john commented to share your HTML and CSS, you should edit your question and add your CSS,HTML, javascript with a snippet. not sharing here in answer.